# Applied bootstrap, then table cells collapsed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I added bootstrap to my page to solve a different problem, then I noticed that my table cells in another place had all collapsed:

[image: collapsed table cells]

How do I get the cells to auto size to their contents? I've seen posts about changing the width of cells, but I need to change their height back to their pre-bootstrap settings.

Here is my code:

```css
.countdown_table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.countdown_table tr td {
  font-family: 'proxima-nova', sans-serif;
  padding-right: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.units {
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.numbers {
  font-size: 700%;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #e18b35 !important;
  font-family: 'proxima-nova', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

#secondElem {
  width: 97px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="countdown_table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="numbers" id="dayElem">04</td>
    <td class="numbers">:</td>
    <td class="numbers" id="hourElem">02</td>
    <td class="numbers">:</td>
    <td class="numbers" id="minuteElem">47</td>
    <td class="numbers">:</td>
    <td class="numbers" id="secondElem">04</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="units">
    <td>days</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>hours</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>minutes</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>seconds</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: When running the code you have attached, there is clearly some stuff missing, i.e. the values for days, hours, minutes and secons plus some CSS (bottom row with white background and white font color?), can you attach a working version of your code where we can recreate the error, i see no conflict with what you've posted and bootstrap

Comment: @randomguy04: those come in from jquery. I'll put in dummy values.